# `strtof()` conversion error by more than 0.5 ULP

Tags: c, floating-point

Why, with `strtof()` "3.40282356779733**650000**e38" unexpectantly converted to infinity even though it is within 0.5 ULP of `FLT_MAX`?

---

`FLT_MAX` ([float32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format)) is  0x1.fffffep+127 or about 3.4028234663852885981170e+38.

1/2 [ULP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place) above `FLT_MAX` is 0x1.ffffffp+127 or about 3.40282356779733**66163754**e+38, so I expected any decimal text below this and the lower `FLT_MAX` to convert to `FLT_MAX` when in "round to nearest" mode.

This works as decimal text increases from `FLT_MAX` to about 3.4028235677973388**642700**e38, yet for decimal text values about above that like "3.40282356779733**650000**e38", the conversion result is *infinity*.

Follows is code that reveals the issue.  It gently creeps up a decimal text string, looking for the value in which conversion changes to *infinity*.
Your results may differ as not all C implementations use the same floating point.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <float.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void bar(unsigned n) {
  char buf[100];
  assert (n < 90);
  int len = sprintf(buf, "%.*fe%d", n+1, 0.0, FLT_MAX_10_EXP);
  puts(buf);
  printf("%-*s   %-*s       %s\n", len, "string", n+3, "float", "double");
  float g = 0;
  for (unsigned i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int digit = '1'; digit <= '9'; digit++) {
      unsigned offset = i ? 1+i : i;
      buf[offset]++;
      errno = 0;
      float f = strtof(buf, 0);
      if (errno) {
        buf[offset]--;
        break;
      }
      g = f;
    }
    printf("\"%s\" %.*e %a\n", buf, n + 3, g, atof(buf));
  }
  double delta = FLT_MAX - nextafterf(FLT_MAX, 0);
  double flt_max_ulp_d2 = FLT_MAX + delta/2.0;
  printf(" %.*e %a FLT_MAX + 1/2 ULP - 1 dULP\n", n + 3, nextafter(flt_max_ulp_d2,0),nextafter(flt_max_ulp_d2,0));
  printf(" %.*e %a FLT_MAX + 1/2 ULP\n", n + 3, flt_max_ulp_d2,flt_max_ulp_d2);
  printf(" %.*e %a FLT_MAX\n", n + 3, FLT_MAX, FLT_MAX);
  printf(" 1 23456789 123456789 123456789\n");
  printf("FLT_ROUNDS %d  (0: toward zero, 1: to nearest)\n", FLT_ROUNDS);
}

int main() {
  printf("%a %.20e\n", FLT_MAX, FLT_MAX);
  printf("%a\n", strtof("3.40282356779733650000e38", 0));
  printf("%a\n", strtod("3.40282356779733650000e38", 0));
  printf("%a\n", strtod("3.4028235677973366163754e+3", 0));
  bar(19);
}
```

Output

```
0x1.fffffep+127 3.40282346638528859812e+38
inf
0x1.ffffffp+127
0x1.a95a5aaada733p+11
0.00000000000000000000e38
string                      float                        double
"3.00000000000000000000e38" 3.0000000054977557577780e+38 0x1.c363cbf21f28ap+127
"3.40000000000000000000e38" 3.3999999521443642490773e+38 0x1.ff933c78cdfadp+127
"3.40000000000000000000e38" 3.3999999521443642490773e+38 0x1.ff933c78cdfadp+127
"3.40200000000000000000e38" 3.4020000005553803402978e+38 0x1.ffe045fe9918p+127
"3.40280000000000000000e38" 3.4027999387901483621794e+38 0x1.ffff169a83f08p+127
"3.40282000000000000000e38" 3.4028200183756559773331e+38 0x1.ffffdbd19d02cp+127
"3.40282300000000000000e38" 3.4028230607370965250836e+38 0x1.fffff966ad924p+127
"3.40282350000000000000e38" 3.4028234663852885981170e+38 0x1.fffffe54daff8p+127
"3.40282356000000000000e38" 3.4028234663852885981170e+38 0x1.fffffeec5116ep+127
"3.40282356700000000000e38" 3.4028234663852885981170e+38 0x1.fffffefdfcbbcp+127
"3.40282356770000000000e38" 3.4028234663852885981170e+38 0x1.fffffeffc119p+127
"3.40282356779000000000e38" 3.4028234663852885981170e+38 0x1.fffffefffb424p+127
"3.40282356779700000000e38" 3.4028234663852885981170e+38 0x1.fffffeffffc85p+127
"3.40282356779730000000e38" 3.4028234663852885981170e+38 0x1.fffffefffff9fp+127
"3.40282356779733000000e38" 3.4028234663852885981170e+38 0x1.fffffefffffeep+127
"3.40282356779733600000e38" 3.4028234663852885981170e+38 0x1.fffffeffffffep+127

"3.40282356779733640000e38" 3.4028234663852885981170e+38 0x1.fffffefffffffp+127 <-- Actual
"3.40282356779733660000e38" 3.4028234663852885981170e+38 ...                    <-- Expected

"3.40282356779733642000e38" 3.4028234663852885981170e+38 0x1.fffffefffffffp+127
"3.40282356779733642700e38" 3.4028234663852885981170e+38 0x1.fffffefffffffp+127
 3.4028235677973362385861e+38 0x1.fffffefffffffp+127 FLT_MAX + 1/2 ULP - 1 dULP
 3.4028235677973366163754e+38 0x1.ffffffp+127 FLT_MAX + 1/2 ULP
 3.4028234663852885981170e+38 0x1.fffffep+127 FLT_MAX
 1 23456789 123456789 123456789
FLT_ROUNDS 1  (0: toward zero, 1: to nearest)
```

---

Notes: GNU C11 (GCC) version 11.3.0 (x86_64-pc-cygwin)
compiled by GNU C version 11.3.0, GMP version 6.2.1, MPFR version 4.1.0, MPC version 1.2.1, isl version isl-0.25-GMP

[Edit]
The exact value of `FLT_MAX + 1/2 ULP`:
0x1.ffffffp+127 340282356779733**661637539395458142568448**.0

I stumbled on this problem today when trying to determine the **maximum decimal text passed to  `strtof()` that returned a finite `float`**.

Comment: With Intel(R) C++ Intel(R) 64 Compiler Classic Version 2021.8.0 on Win64: `strtof ("3.4028235677973366163753e38", 0);` = `FLT_MAX`, while `strtof ("3.4028235677973366163754e38", 0);` = `INFINITY`. So the observation is definitely toolchain specific.

Comment: @njuffa Thanks.  I have determine that the exact threshold is 0x1.ffffffp+127 aka 340282356779733661637539395458142568448.0

Answer (score 4):

This is a [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) answer.  Other answers are welcomed.

> Why, with `strtof()` "3.40282356779733**650000**e38" unexpectantly converted to infinity even though it is within 0.5 ULP of `FLT_MAX`?

Certainly [double rounding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Double_rounding).
"Double" here refers to doing something twice, not the type `double`.

Let 1/2 of a **`float`** [ULP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place) above `FLT_MAX` is 0x1.ffffffp+127 or about 3.40282356779733**66163754**e+38 is called *threshold*.

About 3.40282356733**64274808**e38 is one half of a **`double`** ULP below *threshold*.  Apparently values like "3.40282356779733**650000**e38" **prematurely rounds** as a `double` to *threshold*.  *threshold*, as a `float`, is half-way between `FLT_MAX` and the next larger `float` (if the encoding was extended).  Being a half-way tie, it rounds to the "even" value - the larger one in this case.  Since the next larger `float` is beyond the max encodable finite value, the result is *infinity*.

**Conclusions**

- A better `strtof()` would correctly handle this corner case.
- Instead, it is reasonable to consider decimal places past `FLT_DECIMAL_DIG + 3`  (see following) in `strtof()` as noise.

---

In an alternative `strtof()` implementation, [IEEE_754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) allows such decimal text conversions to treat all the decimal digits passed a certain significance as zero.  This, thus allowing conversions to the 2nd closest `float` when near the 1/2 way point of 2 `float`s.  With common `float`, that significance is `FLT_DECIMAL_DIG + 3` or 12 decimal places.  That is not used here as decimals in the 19th place affect the result.

Comment: I haven't gone through your code carefully, but does this have anything to do with floats being converted to double for variadic arguments?

Comment: @BrettHale, no nothing to do with floats being converted to double for variadic arguments, just `strtof()`.

Comment: On darwin 19.6.0 (catalina) where math libraries have Sun / BSD ancestry, I get: "3.40282356779733600000e38" 3.4028234663852885981170e+38 0x1.fffffeffffffep+127
"3.40282356779733660000e38" 3.4028234663852885981170e+38 0x1.ffffffp+127
"3.40282356779733661000e38" 3.4028234663852885981170e+38 0x1.ffffffp+127
"3.40282356779733661600e38" 3.4028234663852885981170e+38 0x1.ffffffp+127

Comment: @BrettHale Thanks, Looks like a better `strtof()`. What are the next few lines (try `bar(19+4);`

Comment: "3.402823567797336616300000e38" 3.40282346638528859811704183e+38 0x1.ffffffp+127
"3.402823567797336616370000e38" 3.40282346638528859811704183e+38 0x1.ffffffp+127
"3.402823567797336616375000e38" 3.40282346638528859811704183e+38 0x1.ffffffp+127
"3.402823567797336616375300e38" 3.40282346638528859811704183e+38 0x1.ffffffp+127

Comment: Although it's probably deep in the [`libc`](https://github.com/apple-oss-distributions/Libc) code, and has nothing to do with the `libm` implementation, now I think about it.

Comment: @BrettHale Awesome that your implementation was correct for at least 10 more bits.  I suspect its even correct for more.  Thanks again.