# Why addition error near `DBL_MAX` and infinity?

Tags: c, floating-point, infinity

In experimenting with rounding modes, `FE_DOWNWARD` ( and `FE_TOWARDZERO`) apparently fails to form the expected sum of *infinity* and instead forms `DBL_MAX` when adding `DBL_MAX` and 1 [ULP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place) of `DBL_MAX`.

Follows is test code that demos the unexpected sum.  Under different rounds modes, it adds to `DBL_MAX` values near 0.5 ULP and 1.0 ULP.  No problems noted in `FE_TONEAREST` and `FE_UPWARD`.

Questions:

1. Do you agree it is an error?
2. Does code form the correct answer on another machine?
3. This sadly follows another [near `DBL_MAX` problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75227883/2410359) recently reported, so perhaps my math library is sub-par.  Advice on how to report is requested.

Compiler notes:
Invoking: Cygwin C Compiler
gcc -std=c11 -O0 -g3 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -c -fmessage-length=0 -v -MMD -MP -MF"rand_i.d" -MT"rand_i.o" -o "rand_i.o" "../rand_i.c"
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
Target: x86_64-pc-cygwin
gcc version 11.3.0 (GCC)
GNU C11 (GCC) version 11.3.0 (x86_64-pc-cygwin)
compiled by GNU C version 11.3.0, GMP version 6.2.1, MPFR version 4.1.0, MPC version 1.2.1, isl version isl-0.25-GMP

---

```
#include <fenv.h>
#include <float.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define STRINGIFY(x) #x
#define TOSTRING(x) STRINGIFY(x)

int main() {
  const double max = DBL_MAX;
  const double max_ulp = max - nextafter(max, 0);

  int mode[] = {FE_DOWNWARD, FE_TONEAREST, FE_TOWARDZERO, FE_UPWARD};
  const char *modes[] = {STRINGIFY(FE_DOWNWARD), STRINGIFY(FE_TONEAREST), //
      STRINGIFY(FE_TOWARDZERO), STRINGIFY(FE_UPWARD)};
  int n = sizeof mode / sizeof mode[0];
  int p = (DBL_MANT_DIG + 2)/4;
  int P = (LDBL_MANT_DIG + 2)/4;
  printf("%s:%d\n", STRINGIFY(FLT_EVAL_METHOD), FLT_EVAL_METHOD);

  printf("LDBL_MAX   :%-24.*La %.*Lg\n", P, LDBL_MAX, LDBL_DECIMAL_DIG, LDBL_MAX);
  printf("DBL_MAX    :%-24.*a %.*g\n", p, max, DBL_DECIMAL_DIG, max);
  printf("DBL_MAX_ULP:%-24.*a %.*g\n", p, max_ulp, DBL_DECIMAL_DIG, max_ulp);
  printf("\n");
  printf("mode:               Addendum                          SUM (double)                 SUM (long double)\n");
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (fesetround(mode[i])) {
      perror("Invalid mode");
      return -1;
    }
    double delta[] = {nextafter(max_ulp / 2, 0), max_ulp / 2, //
        nextafter(max_ulp / 2, INFINITY), nextafter(max_ulp, 0), //
        max_ulp, nextafter(max_ulp, INFINITY)};
    const char *deltas[] = { "0.5 ulp-", "0.5 ulp", "0.5 ulp+", //
        "ulp-", "ulp", "ulp+"};
    int dn = sizeof delta / sizeof delta[0];
    for (int d = 0; d < dn; d++) {
      double sum = max + delta[d];
      printf("mode:%-14s %-8s:%-24.*a sum:%-24.*a %-24.*La\n", //
          modes[i],  deltas[d], p, delta[d], p, sum, P, 0.0L + max + delta[d]);
    }
    puts("");
  }
}
```

Output: note 4 *unexpected* lines.

```
FLT_EVAL_METHOD:0
LDBL_MAX   :0x1.fffffffffffffffep+16383 1.18973149535723176502e+4932
DBL_MAX    :0x1.fffffffffffffp+1023  1.7976931348623157e+308
DBL_MAX_ULP:0x1.0000000000000p+971   1.9958403095347198e+292

mode:               Addendum                          SUM (double)                 SUM (long double)
mode:FE_DOWNWARD    0.5 ulp-:0x1.fffffffffffffp+969   sum:0x1.fffffffffffffp+1023  0x1.fffffffffffff7fep+1023
mode:FE_DOWNWARD    0.5 ulp :0x1.0000000000000p+970   sum:0x1.fffffffffffffp+1023  0x1.fffffffffffff800p+1023
mode:FE_DOWNWARD    0.5 ulp+:0x1.0000000000001p+970   sum:0x1.fffffffffffffp+1023  0x1.fffffffffffff800p+1023
mode:FE_DOWNWARD    ulp-    :0x1.fffffffffffffp+970   sum:0x1.fffffffffffffp+1023  0x1.fffffffffffffffep+1023
mode:FE_DOWNWARD    ulp     :0x1.0000000000000p+971   sum:0x1.fffffffffffffp+1023  0x1.0000000000000000p+1024
                                                      --> inf expected <--
mode:FE_DOWNWARD    ulp+    :0x1.0000000000001p+971   sum:0x1.fffffffffffffp+1023  0x1.0000000000000000p+1024
                                                      --> inf expected <--

mode:FE_TONEAREST   0.5 ulp-:0x1.fffffffffffffp+969   sum:0x1.fffffffffffffp+1023  0x1.fffffffffffff800p+1023
mode:FE_TONEAREST   0.5 ulp :0x1.0000000000000p+970   sum:inf                      0x1.fffffffffffff800p+1023
mode:FE_TONEAREST   0.5 ulp+:0x1.0000000000001p+970   sum:inf                      0x1.fffffffffffff800p+1023
mode:FE_TONEAREST   ulp-    :0x1.fffffffffffffp+970   sum:inf                      0x1.0000000000000000p+1024
mode:FE_TONEAREST   ulp     :0x1.0000000000000p+971   sum:inf                      0x1.0000000000000000p+1024
mode:FE_TONEAREST   ulp+    :0x1.0000000000001p+971   sum:inf                      0x1.0000000000000000p+1024

mode:FE_TOWARDZERO  0.5 ulp-:0x1.fffffffffffffp+969   sum:0x1.fffffffffffffp+1023  0x1.fffffffffffff7fep+1023
mode:FE_TOWARDZERO  0.5 ulp :0x1.0000000000000p+970   sum:0x1.fffffffffffffp+1023  0x1.fffffffffffff800p+1023
mode:FE_TOWARDZERO  0.5 ulp+:0x1.0000000000001p+970   sum:0x1.fffffffffffffp+1023  0x1.fffffffffffff800p+1023
mode:FE_TOWARDZERO  ulp-    :0x1.fffffffffffffp+970   sum:0x1.fffffffffffffp+1023  0x1.fffffffffffffffep+1023
mode:FE_TOWARDZERO  ulp     :0x1.0000000000000p+971   sum:0x1.fffffffffffffp+1023  0x1.0000000000000000p+1024
                                                      --> inf expected <--
mode:FE_TOWARDZERO  ulp+    :0x1.0000000000001p+971   sum:0x1.fffffffffffffp+1023  0x1.0000000000000000p+1024
                                                      --> inf expected <--

mode:FE_UPWARD      0.5 ulp-:0x1.fffffffffffffp+969   sum:inf                      0x1.fffffffffffff800p+1023
mode:FE_UPWARD      0.5 ulp :0x1.0000000000000p+970   sum:inf                      0x1.fffffffffffff800p+1023
mode:FE_UPWARD      0.5 ulp+:0x1.0000000000001p+970   sum:inf                      0x1.fffffffffffff802p+1023
mode:FE_UPWARD      ulp-    :0x1.fffffffffffffp+970   sum:inf                      0x1.0000000000000000p+1024
mode:FE_UPWARD      ulp     :0x1.0000000000000p+971   sum:inf                      0x1.0000000000000000p+1024
mode:FE_UPWARD      ulp+    :0x1.0000000000001p+971   sum:inf                      0x1.0000000000000002p+1024
```

Comment: gcc 4.8.5 on CentOS 7 generates the same output for `double` values, though `long double` is different.

Comment: `LDBL_MAX   :0xf.fffffffffffffff0p+16380 1.18973149535723176502e+4932`

Comment: @dbush `long double` values are the same, just shifted in  printing.  `0xf.fffffffffffffff0p+16380 == 0x1.fffffffffffffffep+16383`  Still thanks for the insight.

Comment: I believe this is expected behaviour - you should see the same if you evaluate (for example) `DBL_MAX + DBL_MAX` with rounding direction `FE_DOWNWARD`. It has to do with default exception handling for the overflow exception. The relevant part of IEEE 754 is 7.4 (b): "roundTowardZero carries all overflows to the format’s largest finite number with the sign of the intermediate result." and (c): "roundTowardNegative carries positive overflows to the format’s largest finite number, and carries negative overflows to -inf".

Comment: I can write up a proper answer much later (after work), but Eric Postpischil will probably beat me to it. :-)

Comment: @MarkDickinson Yes, I do see the same (non-infinite) result with `DBL_MAX + DBL_MAX`.  The cite is _very_ informative - worthy as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Checking for and dealing with overflow happens in two stages. Note that the actual software/circuitry may use a different strategy, but the result will be *as if* this were the procedure.

1. The infinite-precision result of the computation is rounded, with rules based on the current rounding mode, but with no limits on the exponent. During this stage there's no such thing as "infinity", but the numbers can get as big as they need to get.
2. If the result is outside the representable range, it is "corrected" to be within the representable range, in a manner based on the rounding mode. For `FE_NEAREST` (the "normal" mode) the number is corrected to infinity. For `FE_TOWARDZERO`, however, it's corrected to `+/-DBL_MAX`. (For the other rounding modes it depends on sign: rounding away from zero leads to infinity and rounding toward zero leads to `+/-DBL_MAX`.)

The overflow rules for a given mode are thus *reminiscent* of the rounding rules for that mode, but not really the same. Arguably `FE_NEAREST` is the weird one, since it acts like the (IEEE-754-only) ties-away-from-zero rounding mode under all out-of-range situations, rather than noticing that infinity is *way farther away* than `DBL_MAX`. But the basic behavior for the other modes is to output `+/-DBL_MAX` when its preferred direction (given the sign) is toward zero, and infinity when its preferred direction is away from zero.

Also note that when the result of stage 1 is a value outside the representable range, an overflow exception will still be emitted even when the result of stage 2 is `DBL_MAX`. The overflow doesn't indicate "I made an infinity", but "I had to do stage 2".

Comment: Agree about #1.  And in the case with `DBL_MAX + ulp`, "with no limits on the exponent", the exact sum is `0x1.0000000000000000p+1024` - so rounding mode is not so important yet.  It is #2 that I need to review more concerning `FE_TOWARDZERO`.... Hmmm

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica It's easiest if you forget about `FE_NEAREST` behavior and just think of it as "infinity is up, `DBL_MAX` is down". Those are the two nearest choices.

Comment: The light is beginning to shine through yet the 2 steps, _both_ involving rounding mode seems amiss.  Is not that the computation done as if it had infinite precision and no limits on the exponent.  If the result is not exactly representable as a `double`, the rounding mode is applied once?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Sure, but that doesn't describe the exception-raising behavior, and it doesn't *really* describe where infinity comes from (particularly for `FE_NEAREST`). But it definitely works for the value behavior for the other rounding modes.

Answer (score 0):

[@Sneftel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75309842/2410359) idea to use a 2 stage rounding model was useful and well explains why my expected result was amiss and the code was right.

Below, for reference, is augmented code that posts the overflow flag and helps illustrates the models application.

```
#include <fenv.h>
#include <float.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define STRINGIFY(x) #x
#define TOSTRING(x) STRINGIFY(x)

const char* exceptstr(fexcept_t *flag) {
  static char buf[100];
  buf[0] = 0;
  if (*flag & FE_DIVBYZERO)
    strcat(buf, STRINGIFY(FE_DIVBYZERO));
  if (*flag & FE_INEXACT)
    strcat(buf, STRINGIFY(FE_INEXACT));
  if (*flag & FE_INVALID)
    strcat(buf, STRINGIFY(FE_INVALID));
  if (*flag & FE_OVERFLOW)
    strcat(buf, STRINGIFY(FE_OVERFLOW));
  if (*flag & FE_UNDERFLOW)
    strcat(buf, STRINGIFY(FE_UNDERFLOW));
  return buf;
}

int main() {
  const double max = DBL_MAX;
  const double max_ulp = max - nextafter(max, 0);

  int mode[] = {FE_DOWNWARD, FE_TONEAREST, FE_TOWARDZERO, FE_UPWARD};
  const char *modes[] = {STRINGIFY(FE_DOWNWARD), STRINGIFY(FE_TONEAREST), //
  STRINGIFY(FE_TOWARDZERO), STRINGIFY(FE_UPWARD)};
  int n = sizeof mode / sizeof mode[0];
  int p = (DBL_MANT_DIG + 2) / 4;
  int P = (LDBL_MANT_DIG + 2) / 4;
  printf("%s:%d\n", STRINGIFY(FLT_EVAL_METHOD), FLT_EVAL_METHOD);

  printf("LDBL_MAX   :%-24.*La %.*Lg\n", P, LDBL_MAX, LDBL_DECIMAL_DIG,
  LDBL_MAX);
  printf("DBL_MAX    :%-24.*a %.*g\n", p, max, DBL_DECIMAL_DIG, max);
  printf("DBL_MAX_ULP:%-24.*a %.*g\n", p, max_ulp, DBL_DECIMAL_DIG, max_ulp);
  printf("\n");
  printf(
      "mode:               Addendum                          SUM (double)                 SUM (long double)          FE\n");
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (fesetround(mode[i])) {
      perror("Invalid mode");
      return -1;
    }
    double delta[] = {nextafter(max_ulp / 2, 0), max_ulp / 2, //
    nextafter(max_ulp / 2, INFINITY), nextafter(max_ulp, 0), //
    max_ulp, nextafter(max_ulp, INFINITY)};
    const char *deltas[] = {"0.5 ulp-", "0.5 ulp", "0.5 ulp+", //
        "ulp-", "ulp", "ulp+"};
    int dn = sizeof delta / sizeof delta[0];
    for (int d = 0; d < dn; d++) {
      if (feclearexcept(FE_ALL_EXCEPT)) {
        perror("feclearexcept()");
        return -1;
      }
      ///////////////////////////////
      double sum = max + delta[d];
      ///////////////////////////////
      fexcept_t flag;
      if (fegetexceptflag(&flag, FE_ALL_EXCEPT)) {
        perror("fegetexceptflag()");
        return -1;
      }

      printf(
          "mode:%-14s %-8s:%-24.*a sum:%-24.*a %-24.*La %s\n", //
          modes[i], deltas[d], p, delta[d], p, sum, P, 1.0L * max + delta[d],
          exceptstr(&flag));
    }
    puts("");
  }
}
```

Output (Look to the far right)

```
FLT_EVAL_METHOD:0
LDBL_MAX   :0x1.fffffffffffffffep+16383 1.18973149535723176502e+4932
DBL_MAX    :0x1.fffffffffffffp+1023  1.7976931348623157e+308
DBL_MAX_ULP:0x1.0000000000000p+971   1.9958403095347198e+292

mode:               Addendum                          SUM (double)                 SUM (long double)          FE
mode:FE_DOWNWARD    0.5 ulp-:0x1.fffffffffffffp+969   sum:0x1.fffffffffffffp+1023  0x1.fffffffffffff7fep+1023 FE_INEXACT
mode:FE_DOWNWARD    0.5 ulp :0x1.0000000000000p+970   sum:0x1.fffffffffffffp+1023  0x1.fffffffffffff800p+1023 FE_INEXACT
mode:FE_DOWNWARD    0.5 ulp+:0x1.0000000000001p+970   sum:0x1.fffffffffffffp+1023  0x1.fffffffffffff800p+1023 FE_INEXACT
mode:FE_DOWNWARD    ulp-    :0x1.fffffffffffffp+970   sum:0x1.fffffffffffffp+1023  0x1.fffffffffffffffep+1023 FE_INEXACT
mode:FE_DOWNWARD    ulp     :0x1.0000000000000p+971   sum:0x1.fffffffffffffp+1023  0x1.0000000000000000p+1024 FE_INEXACTFE_OVERFLOW
mode:FE_DOWNWARD    ulp+    :0x1.0000000000001p+971   sum:0x1.fffffffffffffp+1023  0x1.0000000000000000p+1024 FE_INEXACTFE_OVERFLOW

mode:FE_TONEAREST   0.5 ulp-:0x1.fffffffffffffp+969   sum:0x1.fffffffffffffp+1023  0x1.fffffffffffff800p+1023 FE_INEXACT
mode:FE_TONEAREST   0.5 ulp :0x1.0000000000000p+970   sum:inf                      0x1.fffffffffffff800p+1023 FE_INEXACTFE_OVERFLOW
mode:FE_TONEAREST   0.5 ulp+:0x1.0000000000001p+970   sum:inf                      0x1.fffffffffffff800p+1023 FE_INEXACTFE_OVERFLOW
mode:FE_TONEAREST   ulp-    :0x1.fffffffffffffp+970   sum:inf                      0x1.0000000000000000p+1024 FE_INEXACTFE_OVERFLOW
mode:FE_TONEAREST   ulp     :0x1.0000000000000p+971   sum:inf                      0x1.0000000000000000p+1024 FE_INEXACTFE_OVERFLOW
mode:FE_TONEAREST   ulp+    :0x1.0000000000001p+971   sum:inf                      0x1.0000000000000000p+1024 FE_INEXACTFE_OVERFLOW

mode:FE_TOWARDZERO  0.5 ulp-:0x1.fffffffffffffp+969   sum:0x1.fffffffffffffp+1023  0x1.fffffffffffff7fep+1023 FE_INEXACT
mode:FE_TOWARDZERO  0.5 ulp :0x1.0000000000000p+970   sum:0x1.fffffffffffffp+1023  0x1.fffffffffffff800p+1023 FE_INEXACT
mode:FE_TOWARDZERO  0.5 ulp+:0x1.0000000000001p+970   sum:0x1.fffffffffffffp+1023  0x1.fffffffffffff800p+1023 FE_INEXACT
mode:FE_TOWARDZERO  ulp-    :0x1.fffffffffffffp+970   sum:0x1.fffffffffffffp+1023  0x1.fffffffffffffffep+1023 FE_INEXACT
mode:FE_TOWARDZERO  ulp     :0x1.0000000000000p+971   sum:0x1.fffffffffffffp+1023  0x1.0000000000000000p+1024 FE_INEXACTFE_OVERFLOW
mode:FE_TOWARDZERO  ulp+    :0x1.0000000000001p+971   sum:0x1.fffffffffffffp+1023  0x1.0000000000000000p+1024 FE_INEXACTFE_OVERFLOW

mode:FE_UPWARD      0.5 ulp-:0x1.fffffffffffffp+969   sum:inf                      0x1.fffffffffffff800p+1023 FE_INEXACTFE_OVERFLOW
mode:FE_UPWARD      0.5 ulp :0x1.0000000000000p+970   sum:inf                      0x1.fffffffffffff800p+1023 FE_INEXACTFE_OVERFLOW
mode:FE_UPWARD      0.5 ulp+:0x1.0000000000001p+970   sum:inf                      0x1.fffffffffffff802p+1023 FE_INEXACTFE_OVERFLOW
mode:FE_UPWARD      ulp-    :0x1.fffffffffffffp+970   sum:inf                      0x1.0000000000000000p+1024 FE_INEXACTFE_OVERFLOW
mode:FE_UPWARD      ulp     :0x1.0000000000000p+971   sum:inf                      0x1.0000000000000000p+1024 FE_INEXACTFE_OVERFLOW
mode:FE_UPWARD      ulp+    :0x1.0000000000001p+971   sum:inf                      0x1.0000000000000002p+1024 FE_INEXACTFE_OVERFLOW
```